# How to define variables in terms of other variables in a mathematica program for simplifying an expression?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement

I'm new to Mathematica and trying to learn it on my own from various internet resources. I have the following question. How do I simplify the expression $$X=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\tag{1}$$ where $a,b,c$ are *real*, *known* expressions in terms of other parameters (say, $x,y,z$). Again $x,y,z$ are in turn *real*, *known* functions of yet another set of real parameters (say, $p,q,r$).

How do I simplify the algebraic expression $X=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$ to obtain $X$ in terms of $p,q,r$. Thank you.

**An example** For an example, consider $a=-x+y+z, b=x-y+z, c=x+y-z$. Then $x=p^2+q^2$, $y=q^2+r^2$ and $z=p^2+r^2$.

Comment: You can try the `Simplify` or the `FullSimplify` commands? It is better to make a MWE to illustrate the issue.

Comment: @Nasser Thanks. But after writing (1) how does one give the inputs i.e., $a=a(x,y,z)$, $b(x,y,z)$, $c(x,y,z)$, and in the next step $x(p,q,r), y(p,q,r), z(p,q,r)$, in order for the mathematica to evaluate $x$ as a function of $p,q,r$ i.e., $x(p,q,r)$?

Comment: Something like `Simplify[expr /. {a -> a[x, y, z], b -> b[x, y, z], c -> c[x, y, z]}]` (and analogously for `p, q, r`) ought to work. We can't give more helpful feedback unless you show your actual expressions.

Comment: @J.M. I have given an example of what I have in mind. Does that help?

Comment: Then, have you tried the operation I suggested?

Comment: Do not forget that you already have `x` in the left-hand part. Give it another name, or you risk to go into a recurrence. What concerns your question, the very first thing to learn in MMa is to give definitions, such as `a=f1[X,Y,Z]; b=f2[X,Y,Z]; c=F3[X,Y,Z]; X=g1[p,q,r]; Y=g2[p,q,r]; Z=g3[p,q,r];` assuming that all the functions `f1....g3` are known to you and you define them explicitly. Evaluate these definitions. Then simply evaluate the expression (1). Done.

Comment: @all Thanks. I'll try and come back.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is answered by the [Applying Transformation Rules tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ApplyingTransformationRules.html) and the [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) documentation page.

For example,

```
a + b /. {a -> x + y, b -> x + x^2}
(* 2 x + x^2 + y *)

a + b /. {a -> x + y, b -> x + x^2} /. {x -> p - q, y -> p + q}
(* p + 2 (p - q) + (p - q)^2 + q *)

Expand[%]
(* 3 p + p^2 - q - 2 p q + q^2 *)
```

Comment: This is really helpful. If it works out I'll accept the answer. @Szabolcs

Answer (score 1):

Define your expressions

```
a[x_, y_, z_]:=−x+y+z
b[x_, y_, z_]:=x−y+z
c[x_, y_, z_]:=x+y−z
```

then

```
x[p_, q_, r_]:=p^2+q^2
y[p_, q_, r_]:=q^2+r^2
z[p_, q_, r_]:=p^2+r^2
```

and finally substitute in your original expresson like so:

```
-b[x[p,q,r],y[p,q,r],z[p,q,r]]...
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't quite understand the last line. I'm trying to compute $X$ using the expression (1). @user42582

Comment: after having evaluated the definitions for `a[x_,y_,z_], b[x_,y_,z_], c[x_,y_,z_],x[p_,q_,r_],y[p_,q_,r_],z[p_,q_,r_]` you should use these newly defined functions in place of $a,b,c$ in your relation (1) eg replace the value of $b$ with `b[x[p,q,r],y[p,q,r],z[p,q,r]]` etc. (Perhaps you should also look at the solution by @Szabolcs above-it depends on a central theme in *Mathematica* :rules and replacing parts of expressions.)